# Linux : How to detect a process that consumes the maximum memory and kill it?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, memory-management, process

Linux : How to detect a process that consumes the maximum memory and kill it using std::thread? I am new to C++ coding, therefore an explanation with C++ code to implement the function would be highly appreciated.
The exact text of the assignment is to write a C++ code that monitors the memory usage of the device and it shall be aware of the device reached in its targeted maximum memory usage. When the thread detects this condition, it shall be able to identify the process which is taking more memory and do the following actions, Check the process against application priority list. If the process is in low priority category, stop the process and restart. Otherwise, inform the user about the memory over run is happened because of the identified process, take the restart based on the user confirmation. Restart shall be device restart or process restart, that will be decided based on the nature of process which is caused this condition · The details shall be captured in the logging file

Comment: `std::thread` is supposed to spawn a thread, not kill a process.

Comment: Show what you have tried, in SO we appreciate that the author is the main interested in solving your problem, then we will help you with suggestions or possible solutions. If you are a beginner I recommend you to look for an easier application.

Comment: What I meant is the process of memory monitoring should happen in the background , so I must use std:: thread. The functionality to be implemented is to detect a process that consumes RAM to a fatal extent and kill it

Comment: Virtual memory size or resident set size? If you can include the exact text of your assignment, it will be easier. Do you already know how to use std::thread?

Comment: No I have not used std::thread yet.

Comment: The exact text of the assignment is to write a C++ code that monitors the memory usage of the device and it shall be aware of the device reached in its targeted maximum memory usage. When the thread detects this condition, it shall be able to identify the process which is taking more memory and do the following actions,
Check the process against application priority list. If the process is in low priority category, stop the process and restart. Otherwise, inform the user about the memory over run is happened  because of the identified process, take the restart based on the user confirmation

Comment: ·         Restart shall be device restart or process restart, that will be decided based on the nature of process which is caused this condition
·         The details shall be captured in the logging file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at the [Linux OOM (Out-of-memory) killer](https://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer).

From this link:

> It is the job of the linux 'oom killer' to sacrifice one or more processes in order to free up memory for the system when all else fails.

So, technically, you don't need to do anything about it. ;-)

But, if you still want to write it yourself according to your own criteria for choosing and killing the victim process, you may create a Linux service (which run in the background all the time) to do that. The sample code is there in the linked article.

Regarding your `std::thread` point, if you already have an executable and you want to spawn a dedicated thread to do this, yes, you can do that also. The logic will simply move into that thread.

**Additional reading:**
[How to Configure the Linux Out-of-Memory Killer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html)